# Can we limit the number of checkstyle errors

Tags: java, ant, checkstyle

I recently started working on a new project which is in a messy state, there are like 10000 checkstyle errors. I can't fix them all in one go but also want to enable "build failure on checkstyle error" in order to ensure that the new code which gets added to the project follows checkstyle rules.

Is there a way to configure checkstyle to fail only if total number of errors go above 10000 threshold?

Comment: Are all checkstyle errors equal? As in, what does this number "10000" mean? 10000 minor indentation errors are less bad than 1 actual bug, right?

Comment: If I were you, I would physically separate new code from old (i.e. have two source folders that are combined for the build) but only run checkstyle on the new code. You can gradually move code over to the "clean" folder as you fix the problems.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17209/how-to-limit-log-file-size-using You could try limiting the size of your output file.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such option in Checkstyle at the moment in the CLI.

You can raise an issue at https://github.com/checkstyle/

You can check out the ant task:

https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/anttask.html

Answer (score 0):

Depending on tooling you use this might be supported there i.e

If you are using Maven then you can configure maxAllowedViolations
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/check-mojo.html#maxAllowedViolations

If you are using TeamCity CI/CD system then you can configure it's "Failure Conditions﻿" to mark a build as failed if the inspection warnings number is higher than in the previous build.